# How do I consume a custom route using attributerouting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, attributerouting

I have a bunch of custom routes defined using AttributeRouting.  I have a function in a controller that is trying to access one of these API functions at /api/GetBatchItems.

GetBatchItems is a function of the controller APIController, similar to:

```
[RouteArea("api")]
public sealed class APIController : ApiController{
    [GET("GetBatches")]
    public IEnumerable<PRAT.Models.EF.EFBatchItem> GetBatches() { ... }
}
```

In another controller, I am trying to get the result.  When browsing directly everything is fine if I do it this way, but I want to be able to use my already defined route, is there a way to do that?  I saw someone mention `HttpAttributeRoutingConfiguration` but I could not find that class anywhere.  I don't want to have to use the `MapHttpRoute` method this way...

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{id}", null);

var server = new HttpServer(config);
var client = new HttpClient(server);

string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/api/APIController/GetBatches";
var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
var content = result.Content;
var model = content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<PRAT.Models.EF.EFBatchItem>>().Result;
if (model == null) return View();
else return View(model);
```

Comment: Would you please provide the sample code to illustrate your statement "In another controller, I am trying to get the result"?

Comment: The second code sample is from the other controller.  I am creating an HttpClient to get me the data.

Comment: 1. What is the url that works browsing directly? http://<yourhost>/api/GetBatches? 2. If both controllers are on the same site, why have one talk to the other over http? Why not have the second controller reference the first one controller's GetBathces() method?

Comment: When browsing directly, it is /api/GetBatches.  I am sure the issue might be that I am doing config.routes.maphttproute, but i dont know how to add the attributerouting custom routes to an httpconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

**TO MAKE YOUR SAMPLE CODE WORK**

Your existing code sample needs two changes to work:

1. make {id} optional, since GetBatches() has no parameter:

   ```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
   ```
2. since HttpConfiguration routes match {controller} to a class named {controller}Controller, change your url calculation to:

   ```
   string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/api/API/GetBatches";
   ```

**SIMPLER VERSION**

Your can use your existing route /api/GetBatches

```
var client = new HttpClient();

string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/api/GetBatches";
var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
var content = result.Content;
var model = content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<MyViewModel>>().Result;
if (model == null) return View();
else return View(model);
```

**EVEN SIMPLER (IF YOU DO NOT NEED HTTP)**

Replace your sample code with this Add this extension class:

```
var model = (new APIController()).GetBatches();
if (model == null) return View();
else return View(model);
```